# qsTrId and .arg(): how to use it?

Tags: qml, qt5

for a project I'm forced to use `qsTrId` for i18n and I'm now in need of arguments in the string.

Sadly, the documentation for the command does not help about.

I've this sample code:

```
Text {
    id: someId
    //% "%1 my translatable suffix!"
    text: qsTrId("my_translatable_id_with_argument").arg("This is")
}
```

It will output the following error:

```
QString::arg: Argument missing: my_translatable_id_with_argument, This is
```

[The documentation for arg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-string.html#arg-method) say it need to work with strings, so I fear that the `my_translatable_id_with_argument` defined for `qsTrId` is used as base string for `.arg` and since there is no `%1` the error is generated.

Anyone has a tip for this situation?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I've tried the following with no success:

```
Text {
    id: someId
    //% "%1 my translatable suffix!"
    text: qsTrId("my_translatable_id_with_argument")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        text = text.arg("This is")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the translation working, and if you don't use `arg(...)` the string with a `%1` is shown?

Comment: The translation is working correctly, if I don't use `.arg()` the `%1` is indeed visible.