# Escape double quotes in qsTrId source string

Tags: internationalization, qml, qt5

For a project I'm working on, I'm forced to use `qsTrid()` that need the following syntax to work:

```
//% "My string"
text: qsTrId('my_string')
```

Until you need to use double quotes there are no drawbacks in using this for simple strings, [still you cannot use arguments normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183038/qstrid-and-arg-how-to-use-it) like you would do for `qsTr()`.

The problem arise when you need something like this:

```
//% "My "super" string"
text: qsTrId('my_super_string')
```

`lupdate` will only see `"My "` as source string, since the double quotes are used as delimiter.

Up to now the best I could achieve is this:

```
//% "My ""super"" string"
```

That will produce `"My super string"`, the string is not broken but is missing the double quotes.

I've tried searching online and in the documentation if there are special rules in this case, but had no luck.

I tried using single quotes but `lupdate` does not see the string at all in this case.

I cannot use `\"` because the source string is used in the other language that will not be translated, but if it is the **only** solution I'll try to propose it.

Anyone know how to correctly escape the double quotes in this situation?

Comment: have you tried variations like \\" and \\\" ?

Comment: @LennartRolland Yes, I get the backslash symbols in the Linguist and also in the other language